# How to recover bloatware

Tags: rooting

I root my panasonic eluga A and delete some bloatware now my google map has stopped navigating my location.
My google map search location and everything is working but gps not working.
Please help me what to do now.

Answer (score 2):

Try to flash your's device again. And you can try Osmand navigation app.

Answer (score 2):

download factory firmware and refalsh it it will restore the system apps you have deleted which will bring back the bloat

Answer (score 0):

1. Unroot your phone.
2. Do a factory reset.

**If Step 2 does not work:**

3. Flash your device's Original Stock rom.
   (You can find it from your device's website)

**A friendly suggestion:
Don't Delete any system app, that you don't know about.
It might be an important one.**